# An example of bounded lattice which is neither distributive nor complemented

Tags: discrete-mathematics, lattice-orders

Is there an example of lattice which is neither distributive nor complemented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many. Here’s one:

```
                                           1  
                                          /|\  
                                         / | \  
                                        a  b  c  
                                       / \ | /  
                                      /   \|/  
                                     d     e  
                                      \   /  
                                       \ /  
                                        0
```

Show that $a$ has no complement and that $a\lor(b\land d)\ne(a\lor b)\land(a\lor c)$.

Comment: I have found an example for a lattice which is distributive but not complemented under the relation "divides" i.e. a set of factors of 4 but can't find a lattice which is neither distributive nor complemented with the relation "divides". Can u suggest an example for that?

Comment: @user221458: What about $\{1,2,3,5,30,60\}$? I’ll take a look at the other two, but it’s been a long time since I did anything with lattices, so I make no guarantees!